# Coolest Knots??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, knot-theory

Out of pure curiosity, what are some of the coolest knots? I suppose there are two categories we could have- cool in terms of properties and cool in terms of aesthetic appeal. To start off, I'll give the 1st prime knot of 7.

[image]

Comment: The $(-2,3,7)$ Pretzel knot.

Comment: [weird looking pretzel...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%E2%88%922,3,7)_pretzel_knot#/media/File:PretzelKnot.jpg)

Comment: [*Gone wild*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_knot).

Answer (score 1):

I think torus knots, such as this $(3,−7)$ three dimensional torus knot, look pretty neat and are aesthetically pleasing:

[image]